# Multiple account with Same Email Meteor.Js account-password

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to enable multiple signup from one email 
so i want to remove both index username and emails.address

here is my code which i am running @server to remove index

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.users._dropIndex({"emails.address":1});
    Meteor.users._dropIndex({"username":1});
});
```

Above code is not working.

```
Accounts.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: passwd,
            profile: {
                createdAt: new Date()
            }
        });
```

Above code always return user already exist